# find theTR based on a specific TD id in the tablel

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a table populated by records of a mysql table. I have set the *id* field of the mysql records to a delete link in the last *td* of each row in the table. When the user clicks on the delete link in a row, the records is deleted from the mysql table using jquery ajax and taat table row must be deleted from the interface too. Since the whole process is done by jquery ajax, I want to remove the table row which contains the deleted id.

Bellow is what I have done!

```
<td><a id="<?php echo $key->id; ?>" onclick="showModal(this.id);" class="btn green" >Delete</a></td>

function showModal(depid){
alert(depid);
$("#portlet-config").modal();
$("#deleteBtn").click(function(){
    var url = "<?php echo base_url().'subjects/deleteRecord/';?>" + depid + "/subjects";
    $.ajax({
        url: url, success: function(result){ // The result is the deleted id
            //console.info(document.getElementById(result).value);
            var lnk = $("td").find("a").attr("id", result);
            lnk.parent('tr').remove();
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Some Technical Issue Raised!");
        }
    });
});
}
```

How can I now delete the row that contains this id?

Comment: Ok...and your question?

Comment: I need to remove the tr that contains a td with id of lets say 31!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#"+result).parent().closest('tr').remove();
```

sample JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/75eLnebn/1/